# SharePoint to Sitecore content migration

Tags: content-migration, sharepoint-connect

We have been asked for migrating content from SharePoint to Sitecore 9. What should be the best way to do this?

Can we use SharePoint Connect (SharePoint Integration Framework) to achieve this or it is just used for integration?

I know there are some paid tools like Kapow and Siteport, but we are looking for open source or free module.

Comment: Can you share a little bit more, about the source content?   are we talking full page structures, or "easily" managed/structured content like lists and so on?

Comment: It mostly structured content like lists and collections. But would like to know, if both cases applicable. 1. Full Page 2. Only Structured Content.

Comment: Eduardo Moraes wrote really cool blog post about things to consider when doing content migration to Sitecore (not SharePoint specific). Take a look -> https://www.avanade.com/en/blogs/techs-and-specs/sitecore/automated-content-migration

Comment: @ArvindGehlot .. How are you planning to migrate data from SharePoint to Sitecore 9 as I have to do the same thing.

Comment: Sharepoint connect can not be used to migrate content from sharepoint to Sitecore. It has to be manual or writing custom scripts. What solution did you adopt for content migration finally?